# When was a package installed?

Tags: package-management

You know the problem: "I didn't change anything"

But now, it's broken. Is there a way to see when some package was installed or a list of all packages sorted by time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For packages that have not been installed via the Software Center but from the command line via apt-get we may view the logfile in `var/log/apt/history.log`.

Answer (score 3):

Open the software centre and chose history tab  you can see the time there.

[image]

Comment: How do I start this from the command line?

Comment: you opening software center ? type software-center
 in terminal

Comment: +1 for the answer; I'm on Kubuntu, though, and there is no `software-center`. I do have "Software Management" and there is a "History" entry hidden in a popup menu but that view is empty :-(

Comment: Why you did'nt include kubuntu in your question ,
you can still install software center in kubuntu

Comment: I don't know what the difference is between Ubuntu and Kubuntu; my guess was that package management was the same because KDE is just the UI layer.

Comment: Yeah .but default application set is diffrent in ubuntu and kubuntu.ubuntu includes gtk apps wheres kubuntu included kde apps ,but still packagemanagement is apt :)